AttributeError: 'RawConfigParser' object has no attribute 'readfp' when running python apps
I encountered the following error when trying to run tuir and also happened with youtube-dl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/tuir", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('tuir==1.29.0', 'console_scripts', 'tuir')())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/bin/tuir", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point
    return next(matches).load()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 205, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/tuir/__main__.py", line 291, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
             ^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/tuir/__main__.py", line 76, in main
    fargs, bindings = Config.get_file(args.get('config'))
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/tuir/config.py", line 134, in get_file
    config.readfp(fp)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'RawConfigParser' object has no attribute 'readfp'. Did you mean: 'read'?


Did you use pip or pip3.  See here.  Read the FAQ

@eyoung100 tried both, same issue

you tried pip3 install tuir?

@eyoung100 yeah, that is what i have tried

Downgrade python to 3.11.x  See here and here.

Thank you it fixed my issue
just something right its only working when i do it inside python env and then python3.11 setup.py install
when i do it in my system i get
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'
but  python-setuptools is installed

If you install it in a virtualenv it needs to stay inside the virtualenv, and the reason the system is complaining is because you can't use tools from inside the virtualenv outside of it. If you want to use it outside, you need to see if it's available in your package manager or very carefully install multiple versions of python in your host OS.

after looking up python311-pip was missing now its working thanks @eyoung100
